# I call session_start() the script hangs and nothing happens

Tags: php, session

I am running php5, however as soon as I call session_start() the script
hangs and nothing happens. Is anyone else experiencing this problem, or
am I doing something incorrectly?

I am using session_start() on index.php and for some reason sometimes
it'll fail. No warnings, no errors, no notices, not even after
prepending error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', TRUE)
before session_start() do I see anything, it just plain dies.

Comment: It dies or it hangs? I mean, does the page continue to load forever?
Are you setting a PHPSESSID? Are the session files being created on the server?

Comment: I'm assuming your script is supposed to have output, right? ("Yes, the toaster is plugged in.") Have you checked your logs?

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons for that, here are a few of them:

A. The session file could be opened exclusively. 
When the file lock is not released properly for whatever reason, it is causing session_start() to hang infinitely on any future script executions.
Workaround: use session_set_save_handler() and make sure the write function uses fopen($file, 'w') instead of fopen($file, 'x')

B. Never use the following in your php.ini file (entropie file to "/dev/random"), this will cause your session_start() to hang:

```
<?php
ini_set("session.entropy_file", "/dev/random");
ini_set("session.entropy_length", "512");
?>
```

C. 
session_start() needs a directory to write to.

You can get Apache plus PHP running in a normal user account. Apache will then of course have to listen to an other port than 80 (for instance, 8080).

Be sure to do the following things:
- create a temporary directory PREFIX/tmp
- put php.ini in PREFIX/lib
- edit php.ini and set session.save_path to the directory you just created

Otherwise, your scripts will seem to 'hang' on session_start().

Comment: First point is even larger problem with long running php processes, for example server-sent events handler. Got a while to find out what was wrong - mod_security and apparmor were the first suspects.